# Using the ready-made function 'any' replace all values ​of 0 of a vector with the value 100

Tags: vector, octave, any

I tried some variations with 'any' but it only shows 0 or 1.

```
v=[0 1 2 4 0 0 0]
v =

   0   1   2   4   0   0   0

>> any(v)
ans = 1
```

Comment: Weird question. You can’t use `any` for this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I suppose you could use any(v,1) as a step in performing logical indexing ... but there's no reason why that would be a more appropriate approach than (v==0) as the logical indexing array instead ...

Comment: So, based on the phrasing of the question, is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of `any`.  It is a logical function that is supposed to "return true (logical 1) if any element of the vector is nonzero" [according to the function help](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/any.html). Hence, the only outputs from any should be 0 or 1 for standard numeric inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `any` to replace `0` with `100`, maybe you can use the following code:

```
v(~arrayfun("any",v)) = 100;
```

or

```
v(~any(v,1)) = 100; % thanks to the idea from @Tasos Papastylianou
```

such that

```
v =

   100     1     2     4   100   100   100
```

Comment: no need for arrayfun, you can pass a second argument to `any` (i.e. `v(~any(v,1))`)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thank you, I add your idea to the answer